# How can I display OSM tiles using Python?

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap

I'm in the process of generating tiles with generate_tiles.py and I'd like to write a Python app to display them instead of having a web interface. Does anything like that already exist or is there information somewhere on how to write such an app myself?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can look/edit your map using a desktop application like Tilemill or QGIS (I can't really guess why are you generating tiles if it is not for a web application).

Tilestache has an internal webserver you can use for testing, it's easy to get it running just using config files.

A few pointers to get you started (or keep you busy for a few weeks):

Server side libraries and applications

- [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/): very easy to use tile server and tile cache
- [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/): underlying library behind tilestache and tilemill
- [TileLite](https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/tilelite/wiki/Home): lightweight Python tile-server
- [MapOSMatic](http://maposmatic.org/): written in Python/Django + mapnik ?

Client side libraries

- [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/): client side library a lot like Google Maps API
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/): makes it easy to put a dynamic map in any web page
- [Wax](http://mapbox.com/wax/): adds common utilities to minimal mapping libraries
- [Modest maps](http://modestmaps.com/): a simple platform to build upon
- [Mapstraction](http://mapstraction.com/): common interface for numerous javascript mapping libraries

Tools for custom map creation

- [Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/): like css for maps (awesome)
- [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/): must have geospatial toolbox for windows

Markers

- [MakiIcons](http://mapbox.com/maki/): A clean point of interest icon set made for web cartography
- [Map Icons Collection](http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/): 700 free icons to use as placemarks

Some related videos from PyCon2012

- [A gentle introduction to GIS](http://pyvideo.org/video/887/a-gentle-introduction-to-gis)
- [Making maps with Python](http://pyvideo.org/video/672/making-maps-with-python)
- [Spatial data and web mapping with Python](http://pyvideo.org/video/680/spatial-data-and-web-mapping-with-python)
- [Making interactive maps for the web](http://pyvideo.org/video/623/making-interactive-maps-for-the-web)

Some interesting applications to get you inspired:

- [8bitcity](http://8bitcity.com/map): if Google Maps was running into an [Atari 2600](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_2600) [River Raid](http://youtu.be/zYLA_uO-XH0) cartridge
- [OpenWhateverMap](http://www.openwhatevermap.org/): a patchwork of different rendering styles

Comment: someone suggested that mapOsMatic should be removed from the list because according to his experience it is not a usable library and the web service is very buggy. I can't confirm but looks like the project is not very active right now.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the OP:

> I'd like to write a Python app to display them instead of having a web interface

I have the same request (more specifically, I need to show an interactive map within an already existing GTK+ desktop application), I didn't see the question answered here, so I went to look for [direct reference information](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks).  There I see three options:

- if you're on KDE: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/KDE_Marble
- if you're on GTK+: http://nzjrs.github.io/osm-gps-map/
- again in GTK+: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Libchamplain

Paulo Scardine very complete overview focuses on web interface, and does not mention them.